# Displaing a web-page partially in android webview

Tags: android, android-webview

Assume that I have a web-page named abc.html as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>

<div class="a"><p>Only display this</p></div>
<div class="b"><p>Don't display this</p></div>
<div class="c"><p>Don't display this</p></div>

</body></html>
```

Can you please give me any idea how can I display only the `<div class="a">` in android webview.

Here is my code to load full web-page

```
public class CustomWebsite extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_website); 

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView_test);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        webView.loadUrl("http://skyasim.info/abc.html");

        }

          public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
            {
                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;

                }
            }           

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could inject your own JS to get rid/hide the other elements. jQuery Example:

```
$("div:not(.a)").remove();
```

Presto, `div`s with any class besides `a` will be removed from the DOM tree.

Otherwise, if you want, you could fetch the data yourself, seek and destroy all `div`s that aren't class `a` yourself and load the string into the webview.